using git-repo - how to get started?
First - I have read lots about using REPO with android.
None of those things I have read help.
I am specifically trying to use REPO out side of android and there seems to be no docs for that situation.
I can: (A) run the REPO command and it creates a .REPO directory
But then I am stuck.
I know I need a "default.xml" or "manifest.xml" which list the sub projects.
I'm not sure where I should or create this, and where should I put the file to start.
My example is this:

I have a Parent project called: MOM
Mom has 3 child projects ALICE, BOB and CHARLIE.
They live in subdirectories of "MOM"
The MOM project contains top level build scripts and such.

I'm getting lost and have lots of questions.
Questions:

So do I place the "manifest.xml" file in the MOM Project?

And where should the .repo directory be located, does this get checked into MOM?
Or does it belong somewhere else? It seems it should be part of MOM?

Or must MOM be instead a separate from the REPO project?

If Given the MOM URL (which is an SSH git checkout URL)
How should a new person on the team check out with REPO?

We want to use the standard feature branch workflow for GIT.
Meaning we would create a feature branch in at least the children.
But do we also create a feature branch in MOM?
Follow up: I can find plenty of "feature branch" things for standard git.
But I find ZERO repo based feature branch details.
GOOGLE is finding nothing but "git feature branch" instructions
And will not find "repo feature branch" instructions.

I have read that REPO generally works with GERRIT...
We do not use GERRIT - we use another GIT web solution is that an issue?

During development - we believe we should have the "PRODUCT" on a PRODUCT_NAME branch.
And - we would feature branch from the PRODUCT_NAME branch,
Eventually merge back to the PRODUCT_NAME branch.
The goal eventually we create a RELEASE branch and work to closure on that.
Finally at some point, we know we need to have the manifest changed
From all things on branches to sha-hash commits.
We would call that step: "pegging" the commits for release.
However - I read that REPO really does SHAS not branches
Or get the impression that REPO can start with BRANCHES but it converts them to shas.
And that would really mess with the way I understand feature branches.



"MOM has 3 child projects ALICE, BOB and CHARLIE.
They live in subdirectories of MOM". This looks like [tag:git-submodules]. Why do you want to use Google's repo instead of submodules?


So do I place the "manifest.xml" file in the MOM Project?

You can, but it's not a recommended practice. Typically, we create a separate repository to store manifest files.

And where should the .repo directory be located, does this get checked into MOM? Or does it belong somewhere else? It seems it should be part of MOM?

The .repo directory does not belong to any specific project in the manifest file. It is created by repo init under the directory where you want to download the projects specified in the manifest file. It is similar to the .git directory, which indicates the root directory of a git repository. The .repo directory indicates the root directory of a workspace of repositories managed by repo. Do not create the .repo directory under another repo workspace, and avoid creating it under $HOME or /.

I have read that REPO generally works with GERRIT... We do not use GERRIT - we use another GIT web solution is that an issue?

It doesn't matter which hosting service you use, whether it's Gerrit, Gitlab, Github, or any other services. As for Gerrit, it's just because Google uses it to maintain AOSP repositories. So do the downstream vendors.

However - I read that REPO really does SHAS not branches Or get the impression that REPO can start with BRANCHES but it converts them to shas. And that would really mess with the way I understand feature branches.

In a manifest file, you can specify to use a branch or a fixed commit for a project. To use a branch, when you run repo sync, you can get the latest commit of the branch. To use a commit or a tag, you always get the fixed commit.
The other questions seem related with how to write a manifest file. From your description, I think you want such a directory structure
├── MOM
│   ├── ALICE
│   │   └── .git
│   ├── BOB
│   │   └── .git
│   ├── CHARLIE
│   │   └── .git
│   ├── .git
│   ├── script_a.sh
│   └── script_b.sh
└── .repo

Suppose you have these repositories:
https://gitlab.abc.com/manifests.git
https://gitlab.abc.com/MOM.git
https://gitlab.abc.com/BOB.git
https://gitlab.abc.com/ALICE.git
https://gitlab.abc.com/CHARLIE.git

The manifest file default.xml in the main branch could be like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="https://gitlab.abc.com" name="origin"/>
  <default remote="origin" revision="PRODUCT_NAME_BRANCH"/>
  <project name="MOM" revision="PRODUCT_NAME_BRANCH"/>
  <project name="ALICE" path="MOM/ALICE"/>
  <project name="BOB" path="MOM/BOB"/>
  <project name="CHARLIE" path="MOM/CHARLIE" revision="RELEASE_NAME_BRANCH"/>
</manifest>

With this manifest, you can get the repositories in the directory structure.
repo init -u https://gitlab.abc.com/manifests.git -m default.xml -b main
repo sync

This manifest works like a branch. The revision of every project is a branch instead of a fixed commit, so we can always get the latest commit of each repository. It's used to get the latest code from PRODUCT_NAME_BRANCH or RELEASE_NAME_BRANCH of each repository. For MOM, the path is missing, so it defaults to the same value of the name. For ALICE and BOB, the revision is missing, so the default revision is used. For CHARLIE, RELEASE_NAME_BRANCH is specified, so the default revision is ignored.
After downloading the code, you may want to record its snapshot.
repo manifest -r -o .repo/manifests/20241213.1057.build.xml
cd .repo/manifests
git add 20241213.1057.build.xml
git commit -m'add 20241213.1057.build.xml'
git push origin main

The contents of 20241213.1057.build.xml would be like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="https://gitlab.abc.com" name="origin"/>
  <default remote="origin" revision="PRODUCT_NAME_BRANCH"/>
  <project name="MOM" path="MOM" revision="fd80e6a12a249dd7fff7b43d8aa9b39fd2714901" upstream="PRODUCT_NAME_BRANCH"/>
  <project name="ALICE" path="MOM/ALICE" revision="27ddd718612bb936be81f5cc79a8ef92a54258ca" upstream="PRODUCT_NAME_BRANCH"/>
  <project name="BOB" path="MOM/BOB" revision="076551b0f2c6f88b4bec3a22328b392a73d28081" upstream="PRODUCT_NAME_BRANCH"/>
  <project name="CHARLIE" path="MOM/CHARLIE" revision="e4d7665d8d629eb71531a73cabeb48032cfb8e26" upstream="RELEASE_NAME_BRANCH"/>
</manifest>

This new manifest works like a tag. It records fixed commits of all the repositories. You or others can use it to download the exactly same code.
repo init -u https://gitlab.abc.com/manifests.git -m 20241213.1057.build.xml -b main
repo sync

For different purposes, you can combine different sets of repositories to generate manifest files. And you can specify different paths, revisions, and other things. It's quite flexible. As to manifest format, see repo Manifest Format online or the local .repo/repo/docs/manifest-format.md.
The manifest serves to record a snapshot of the code or synchronize the code to a fixed snapshot. You can perform other tasks in the downloaded repositories, like switching branches, making commits, or running a build.

thanks i’ll try more tomorrow . how does the festure branch workflow work with repo?

@user3696153 repo has nothing to do with branch workflow. It can be seen as a variant of git clone, working on multiple repositories. After the repositories are downloaded, you can use git to do the workflow.

I see the above answer by ElpieKay explains the aspects of the repo command.
Here is what I think about your last few questions
We want to use the standard feature branch workflow for GIT. Meaning we would create a feature branch in at least the children. But do we also create a feature branch in MOM?
You can follow the regular feature branch merging strategy for the development. You can create a feature branch in the manifest repository and modify the manifest according to the branches you have created. You can have a combination of the 'revision' for different repositories inside the manifest.
I have read that REPO generally works with GERRIT... We do not use GERRIT - we use another GIT web solution is that an issue?
It works fine with other GIT web solutions also, you should have the SSH/HTTPS protocol working fine for the local clones from those sources.
However - I read that REPO really does SHAS not branches Or get the impression that REPO can start with BRANCHES but it converts them to shas. And that would really mess with the way I understand feature branches.
Repo is a wrapper that gets you multiple repositories from your chosen revisions in the manifest to your workspace.
Also, in the workspace you have created using repo init and repo sync, you can choose to create branches and have your normal workflow.
